# Azure Synapse Spark Pool Submission Failure with error message "SparkJobDefinitionActionFailed"

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-synapse

I am following the tutorials below and try to submit a Spark Job using the Spark engine in Azure Synapse.

The submission failed with following error:

```
Error:
{
  "code": "SparkJobDefinitionActionFailed",
  "message": "Spark job batch request for workspace contosows, spark compute contosospark with session id null failed with a system error. Please try again",
  "target": null,
  "details": null,
  "error": null
}
```

Can anyone give some guidance/suggestions on how to resolve it?

More information about my setups.

1. Region: Southeast Asia for both Azure Synapse workspace + ADLS Gen2
2. I grant myself Both Storage Blob Data Owner and Storage Blob Data Contributor roles as suggested.
3. Tutorials used:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/quickstart-create-workspace
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/quickstart-create-apache-spark-pool-portal
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-job-definitions

Thanks!

Comment: Are you still facing the issue ? Are  yoiu using the Python / Scala part ?

Comment: If it is useful for you, could you please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? It may help more people who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

After investigation, the product group deployed a hotfix to fix this problem.

Now you can submit the Spark job without any issues. Please do let me known, if you are experiencing this issue anymore.